# How can i scan a qr code from ARScene Camera usin ARCORE

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Here I need some suggestion or a want to a way of doing this

Scenario: i want to scan a qr code in the ar scene and when i scan the qr code what ever content is there in qr code i will place in the ar scene here i dont want to use google vision instead i want to use the below package but the below package opens camera instead i want to use it in the AR scene it self

I used this package for qr scan https://github.com/zxing/zxing

below is my ar code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArFragment arFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {
          Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
            ModelRenderable.builder()
                    .setSource(this, Uri.parse("anchor.sfb"))
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addModelToScene(anchor,modelRenderable))
                    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage()).show();
                        return  null;
                    });
        });
    }

    private void addModelToScene(Anchor anchor,ModelRenderable modelRenderable){
        AnchorNode anchorNode  = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode transformableNode  = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
        transformableNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        transformableNode.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an epic project, but at least zxing provides Android java source. If someone paid me a small fortune, what I would do is graft the zxing code ontop of the ARCore code...

Comment: You can start by looking at [getResultPoints](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/Result.html#getResultPoints--). This can help to detect the outline of qr code. Then you will need to determine camera position from the quadrilateral and render the object.

Comment: @fdermishin updated the question

Comment: To be clear you don't want to use this ARCore feature: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images but want to create your own?

Comment: @MorrisonChang i want to use the ar core feature along with qr code scan and recently i saw a feature shared ar camera session will it be useful and my scenario is like i want to open the camera and scan the qr code and place the object on / beside qr code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend trying the existing [Augmented Images feature in ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images)

What you think is a QR code, the AR software sees as a [fiducial marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker). These markers need to known beforehand. For example in the video on the ARCore page, the painting is a fiducial marker which allows the 3D image to be overlaid.

The ARCore feature I linked to supports up to 1000 reference images/markers per marker database and you can create and use new predefined marker databases.

As long as you know what QR codes will have 3D effects, you can prepare them in a marker database.

If you want/need to have dynamic QR code with ARCore, I would suggest trying to create fiducial around/next to the QR code so that you can scan and then hand off to AR Core to generate the 3d image, but may not work as QR code may be mixed in with the fiducial both need white space to work.

If you can't use ARCore, then you are in the world of OpenCV and various scene engines (3D renderers) like [Ogre](https://www.ogre3d.org/2020/12/24/augmented-reality-made-simple-with-ogre-and-opencv) or you can draw the AR scene in OpenGL ES.

Comment: One thing im using sceneform 1.17.1 before this i used an older version and able to convert my obj file to sfb but now when ever im doing it is not happening even in gradle properties also if add some thing it is working

Comment: If using sceneform 1.17.1 / 15.0 and using AS plugin see: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/1078#issuecomment-624953475

Comment: i using gltf i mean in runtime im downloading the model https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/raw/master/2.0/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf

Comment: If using glTF then you should be using the open source sceneform version 1.16.0. From https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk the other versions don't support glTF.

Answer (score 0):

ARCore gives you the frame or use a wrapper like sceneform. In sceneform you are able to get your frame from ARFragment.

1. First get your fragment:

```
var arFragment = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_ar_fragment) as ArFragment?)
arFragment.arSceneView?.scene?.addOnUpdateListener {
    onUpdateFrame()
}
```

2. Analyze your frames for example read QR Codes

```
fun onUpdateFrame() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        analyze()
    }
}

private fun analyze() {
    frame = arFragment.arSceneView.arFrame
    //Do fancy stuff with your frame, e.g. reading QR Codes
    readingQRCodes(image)
}

private fun readingQRCodes() {
    val mediaImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, 0)
    val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient()
    scanner.process(mediaImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener { qrCodes ->
            //...      
        }
         .addOnFailureListener {
            //...
        }
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            image.close()
        }
}
```

Of course you can also use the ARCore library to get the camera frames.